# Handling zero multiplied with NaN

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to estimate the entropy of Random Variables (RVs), which involves a calculation of step: `p_X * log(p_X)`. 
For example,

```py
import numpy as np
X = np.random.rand(100)   
binX = np.histogram(X, 10)[0] #create histogram with 10 bins
p_X = binX / np.sum(binX)
ent_X = -1 * np.sum(p_X * np.log(p_X))
```

Sometimes `p_X` shall be zero which mathematically make the whole term as zero. But python makes `p_X * np.log(p_X)` as `NaN` and makes the whole summation as `NaN`. Is there any way to manage (without any explicit checking for NaN) making `p_X * np.log(p_X)` to give zero whenever `p_X` is zero? Any insight and correction is appreciated and Thanks in advance:)

Comment: _..give zero whenever p_X is zero..._ A simple if condition?

Comment: `scipy.special.xlogy`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have `scipy`, use [`scipy.special.xlogy(p_X,p_X)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.xlogy.html). Not only does it solve your problem, as an added benefit it is also a bit faster than `p_X*np.log(p_X)`.

Comment: It's worth noting that `xlogy(0, float("nan"))` returns `nan`, not `0`. So for the case where you are doing `xlogy(x, y)` and want the result to be 0 whenever `x == 0` and `y <= 0`, then this solution works. But if `y` could be a nan value, then you'll still have the possibility of returning a nan value.

Comment: @SJL which is the correct behavior: suppress bogus `NaN`s created by naive evaluation of `0 log 0` but do not hide genuine `NaN`s. Besides, `OP` has `x==y`, so this cannot happen.

Comment: I wasn't implying that the behavior was incorrect, just that some people might incorrectly assume that `xlogy(0, nan)` returned 0.

Comment: @SJL Nor was I implying you were implying ;-) Btw. OP's headline is misleading as `log 0` doesn't return `NaN` but `-infty`, it is the subsequent multiplication that makes it `NaN`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [`np.ma.log`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html), which will mask `0`s and use the  `filled` method to fill the masked array with `0`:

```
np.ma.log(p_X).filled(0)
```

For instance:

```
np.ma.log(range(5)).filled(0)
# array([0.        , 0.        , 0.69314718, 1.09861229, 1.38629436])
```

---

```
X = np.random.rand(100)   
binX = np.histogram(X, 10)[0] #create histogram with 10 bins
p_X = binX / np.sum(binX)
ent_X = -1 * np.sum(p_X * np.ma.log(p_X).filled(0))
```

Answer (score 4):

In your case you can use [`nansum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html) since adding `0` in `sum` is the same thing as ignoring a `NaN`:

```
ent_X = -1 * np.nansum(p_X * np.log(p_X))
```

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it will silently eat NaNs produced by other operations than p_X being zero. Presumably, the OP would prefer NaNs to be kept if one of the p_X is <0, for instance (judging by `without any explicit checking for NaN`).

Comment: @Leporello that's true